# Clarification for "continuation" tag

Tags: discussion

"Continuation" could mean either a family of patent including continuation, divisional, and ᴄɪᴘ, or just "continuation". We need clarification on how questions related to "continuation" should be tagged.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, I would say we should look at the most common use of the tag, clarify it, and make a synonym.

We've currently got three tags that sound like they handle what you're talking about.

- [divisional](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisional)
- [continuation-in-part](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuation-in-part) (and its used-to-be duplicate [cip](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cip), but I've created a synonym for that)
- [continuation](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuation)

It would be nice to clarify what [continuation](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuation) is for via a rename and synonym. I'm open to suggestions of what a more descriptive name might be.

As for choosing which tag to use, I think the presence of these makes it a simpler choice. [continuation](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuation) should be used for questions about continuations. Not continuations in part, not divisionals, just continuations.

There was one question incorrectly tagged with [continuation](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuation) instead of [divisional](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisional), and I've fixed that.

Beyond that, though, I think the best action moving forward will be to add tag wikis to each of these to clarify to new (and experienced) users what should be used when.

Comment: I see a possible issue. A US "continuation" is equivalent to a "divisional" in the rest of the world. A US divisional is just one narrow subspecies of the rest-of-world divisional. Although this site is primarily focused on the US patent system, it will inevitably cover questions from other jurisdictions. It might be confusing if [tag:divisional] only covered US divisionals, since a question about European divisionals should seemingly have the [tag:divisional] tag too. But it also seems that US continuations and non-US divisionals should be together, since they are basically the same thing.

Comment: Which is to say, I don't know the answer! I'm just bringing problems without bringing solutions really.

Comment: In the U.S. stating that a continuing application is a "divisional" conveys a property that can avoid a future double patenting rejection. It really is form over substance. To get tis benefit it must be designated a divisional. This might  possibly give a unique need for the term in the U.S.